# Why isn't my list populating in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, listview

I want to create a simple list of items (names, in this case) in an application. I'm using Android Studio and as far as I know, I have written everything correctly and I don't know where I have gone wrong. Here's my `XML` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.scott.exampleapp.test_page">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And my corresponding Java file:

```
package com.example.scott.exampleapp;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class test_page extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] exampleArray = new String[]{"Scott", "Steffi", "Liam", "Jonny", "Zac"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_page);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_test_page, exampleArray);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` instead of `R.layout.activity_test_page` inside `ArrayAdapter()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your are passing the wrong layout to adapter , it should be the inbuild  `simple_list_item_1`
layout.

use this

```
  ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exampleArray);
```

here `new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_test_page, exampleArray);`  you are using the activity layout , but adapter uses it's own layout to populate `listitems` accordingly so either you can use the inbuild layout or you can also create a separate one (extra coding + extra beauty )

plus you don't have to do this

```
 String[] exampleArray = new String[]{"Scott", "Steffi", "Liam", "Jonny", "Zac"};
```

you can use this without `new String[]` at the time of declaration with initialization

```
 String[] exampleArray = {"Scott", "Steffi", "Liam", "Jonny", "Zac"};
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that and it gives me the error "Couldn't resolve symbol." What does this actually mean?

Comment: @Yoman which symbol? ,post full error  and get result in seconds

Comment: The exact words of the error are "Cannot resolve symbol 'simple_list_item_1'."

Comment: @Yoman you have to write `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` , this `R.layout.simple_list_item_1` won't work because you want to access the sdk resource in this case , not the project's resource

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125489/discussion-between-yo-man-and-pavneet-singh).

Answer (score 4):

You can't use activity layout as List item layout either you have to create new List item layout or use default `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` for ArrayAdapter :

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exampleArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a layout for each row ? You need a layout for that as well that will be used in the constructor of your array adapter.

Create a Layout with a textview for example.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20T[]))

The second parameter used in the constructor is:

> resource  int: The resource ID for a layout file containing a TextView to use when instantiating views.

Use your item layout instead of `R.layout.activity_test_page`

Something like:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, exampleArray);
```

or if you want to use a custom layout:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_item_layout, exampleArray);
```